# when Component is re-rendered, is the function object deleted completely and re-created?

Tags: reactjs

As I know, when component is re-rendered, codes inside component is deleted and re-created
( except when you use useCallback or useMemo ..etc)
but in the following codes, I guess the function object is not deleted but keep it's states no matter the component is re-rendered.

here are the codes

```
import usePromise from '../lib/usePromise';

function NewsList({ category }) {
  const [loading, resolved, error] = usePromise(() => {
    const query = category === 'all' ? '' : `&category=${category}`;
    return axios.get(link,);
  }, [category]);

*** (omit below) ***
}
```

I used custom hook and its deps is 'category'

and here is the custom hook code

it runs promise function which it received and manage the states(loading, resolved, error) and return the states

```
import { useState, useEffect } from 'react';
export default function usePromise(promiseCreator, deps) {
  const [loading, setLoading] = useState(true);
  const [resolved, setResolved] = useState(null);
  const [error, setError] = useState(null);

  useEffect(() => {
    const process = async () => {
      try {
        const resolved = await promiseCreator();
        setResolved(resolved);
      } catch (e) {
        setError(e);
      }
      setLoading(false);
    };
    process();
  }, deps);

  return [loading, resolved, error];
}
```

so here is the question. I thought the usePromise function in NewsList component would be deleted when NewsList re-rendered. and re-created.
so I guessed usePromise function doesn't need deps. (empty array would be fine I thought)
cause when you give empty array as a deps for useEffect. it runs only once the component is mounted.
so I thought even if I give empty array as deps for usePromise function, everything work well.
But it wasn't.
However, when I give *category* as a deps for usePromise function like I wrote above everything worked well.
That means, when NewsList component is re-rendered usePromise is not deleted but keep it's states inside right?
I don't understand this phenomenon cause it's different from what I've learned.
can you explain why it happens?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you write code in your component which *creates* a function, then that creation will happen on every render. However, `usePromise` is not being created, it's just being called. The function was created some time ago, when the /lib/usePromise.js file was loaded.

`usePromise` is a helper function that's letting you reuse some common code in multiple components. It's convenient, but it's not really any different than if that code was in your component. If you copy/pasted the code out of `usePromise` and into your main component, it would behave pretty much exactly the same:

```
function NewsList({ category }) {
  const [loading, setLoading] = useState(true);
  const [resolved, setResolved] = useState(null);
  const [error, setError] = useState(null);

  const promiseCreator = () => {
    const query = category === 'all' ? '' : `&category=${category}`;
    return axios.get(link,);
  };
  useEffect(() => {
    const process = async () => {
      try {
        const resolved = await promiseCreator();
        setResolved(resolved);
      } catch (e) {
        setError(e);
      }
      setLoading(false);
    };
    process();
  }, /* insert deps here */);

  // ...
}
```

So if this code was in the body of the component, then what dependencies would you need to have on the `useEffect`? You would want `[category]`, so that the effect can re-run if the category changes. And the same is true if you move this code into a helper function and name that function `usePromise`.

Comment: what a nice explanation. Thank you so much for explaining in a simple but correct way.
also I didn't know a helper function can be shared on multiple component.
I've learnt one more thing. Thanks